# Windows Mobile 6.5 device is not detected on Windows Mobile Device Center on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

I have a windows mobile 6.5 device which is not being detected by the Windows Mobile Device Center installed on my Windows 7 64 bit machine. I installed the 64 bit version of Windows Mobile Device Center.

The Windows Mobile 6.5 device is detected by the OS but it fails to connect to Windows Mobile Device Center.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Subbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that the device drivers are being installed correctly?
If the device drivers fail to install, Windows Mobile Device Center will never detect that the device is connected and ready for remote connections.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I did check it. My PC is AMD based? Does that make a difference?